# How disable selected option when it been selected in react with antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd in react render a form with dynamic add and remove form.item.
In each form.item I'm trying to set an option which the day disable when it been selected in previous form.item.
So I was thinking about maybe I can use state that can set the day disable.

```js
  const [weekDays, setWeekDays] = useState({
    Monday: false,
    Tuesday: false,
    Wednesday: false,
    Thursday: false,
    Friday: false,
    Saturday: false,
    Sunday: false,
  });
```

And the form was like this

```js
          <Form.List name="classTime">
            {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
              <>
                {fields.map((field) => (
                  <Row key={field.key} align="baseline">
                    <Col span={8}>
                      <Form.Item
                        noStyle
                        shouldUpdate={(prevValues, curValues) =>
                          prevValues.area !== curValues.area ||
                          prevValues.sights !== curValues.sights
                        }
                      >
                        {() => (
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, "weekday"]}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "weekday"]}
                            rules={[
                              { required: true, message: "Missing weekday" },
                            ]}
                          >
                            <Select
                              disabled={false}
                              style={{ width: 130 }}
                              onChange={(value) => {
                                setWeekDays(value.true);
                              }}
                            >
                              {Object.entries(weekDays).map(([item,value]) => (
                                <Option
                                  key={item}
                                  value={item}
                                  disabled={value}
                                >
                                  {item}
                                </Option>
                              ))}
                            </Select>
                          </Form.Item>
                        )}
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={12}>
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, "time"]}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "time"]}
                        // normalize={(value) => moment(value).format("HH:mm:ss")}
                        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing time" }]}
                      >
                        <TimePicker style={{ width: "100%" }} />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={2}>
                      <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                ))}
                <Row>
                  <Col span={20}>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Button
                        type="dashed"
                        onClick={() => add()}
                        block
                        icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                      >
                        Add Class Time
                      </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </>
            )}
          </Form.List>
```

it seems good but when I select a day will error me

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

can't figure out why.

Comment: why options are being computed from the state ?
you can just define a set of options

`const weekdays = [{label: 'Monday', value:'monday'}, ...] `
and then you only track the selected day with setWeekday(value)
your onChange handler is weird , whats value.true ?

Comment: I think its because of Object.entries(weekDays) if weekDays is undefined such an error happen, are you sure weekDays is defined or not null where you used it ?